# Read/Write Google Sheets API on react-native

Tags: react-native, google-sheets, google-api, google-authentication

basically I want to use Google Sheets API on my React Native project to write some data there on a single sheet.

Here are the problems I'm facing after searching for hours:

1. I want to be able to read and write, such as creating new sheets inside the spreadsheet, hence I can't use the public API or an API key.
2. I don't need the user to login, so I can't use the Google sign in API. More like, I want my developer account to be signed in, as I wanna use my own single spreadsheet for all users. Think of it as using it as a database for my app (don't worry, I'm not).
3. I found many wrappers but they're all meant for node and don't work on react native.
4. I'm trying to use the vanilla google APIs, but I'm having trouble getting an "Access Token" as the only way i found to get it was by making a user sign in. I created a Service Account but I can't figure out how to use on react native. The npm module I found doesn't work on react native.

So I guess here is what I'm looking for: either

1. A wrapper for Google Sheets API that takes care of authentication as well.
2. How to get an access_token for my developer account, without prompting the user to sign in.

Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, in your situation, I thought that Web Apps created by Google Apps Script might be able to be used. When Web Apps is used, the authorization can be done when Web Apps is deployed. By this, you can simply use Sheets API and Spreadsheet service by the owner of Web Apps (In this case, I think that you are the owner.) Here, I have a question. In your situation, how many users are you guessing? From this answer, I can think of this method whether this method can be used.

Comment: My question is that I have a react native app, and i wanna keep track of some user info on my doc on my drive. all users on 1 doc. I would estimate like 50 users daily.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that Web Apps created by Google Apps Script might be able to be used for achieving your goal. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)